# print layout for map bug

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I want to create a map with legend and so on but when I actually press New print layout and then I add a map I have a blank (see img attached). Is anyone does know why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNckI.png)
[image][image]

Comment: Did you actually move the map item focus to your map canvas extent?

Comment: the print layout are not pre-made, you need to adjust map scale and extend and to add and configure all other object you need (title, legend, attribution, ...)

Comment: Thank you but how do you do that?